# Is there have rhymes for silver, purple, month, ninth, pint, wolf, opus, dangerous, marathon and discombobulate?

Tags: word-request

I read on internet that **Rhymes** for Words That Have No Rhyme.

> That `silver`, `purple,` `month, ninth, pint, wolf, opus, dangerous, marathon` and `discombobulate.`

And mostly for **Orange** have no rhyme.

So is it true and if, may we try to find out rhymes of these all words?

Comment: What are you asking? How would anyone know a rhyme for words that don't have a rhyme? There are close rhymes, such as **arrange / orange** and **golf / wolf** but they aren't very good ryhmes.

Comment: Many of those words actually have rhymes. I know of chilver, hurple, and sporange for example.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah though I wonder if there would have no rhymes but some may not have for sure. Thank you.

Comment: @WeatherVane Curple -Purple, Circle - Purple.

Comment: To find a rhyme for "silver" / or any "rhymeless" rhyme / requires only will, ver- / bosity and time. - Stephen Sondheim

Comment: Might this question be a better fit for the English Language & Usage site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different kinds of rhyme.

Words that rhyme very closely such as **light** and **sight** are *perfect rhymes*. I think perhaps your statement that certain words do not have a rhyme is referring to perfect rhymes, although a couple on your list are arguably incorrect. There are some lesser-known and/or archaic words such as "*chilver*" (a female lamb) which rhyme perfect well with "silver".

Words that share a syllable are known as *syllabic rhymes*. One of your examples is "silver", and this could be rhymed with the word "cleaver" among others. Other terms for different kind of rhymes also exist.

The website [Rhymezone](https://www.rhymezone.com) is a useful resource for finding all kinds of rhymes. Here are some results from your examples:

**silver**: chilver, bigger, dinner, figure

**purple**: argal, argil, barbel, burble, burgle, carpal

**month**: plinth, lunch, bunch

**ninth**: smythe, scyth, find, mind

Comment: Yeah I mean If we could find perfect rhyme. Examples aren't perfect rhymes so definition of rhyme should be perfectly match then syllabic rhyme wouldn't be considered as a rhyme.